# How to scroll list while using android:background="@drawable/view1"

Tags: android, android-listview

I have number of items in `Listview`, and I have placed an `ImageButton` below my `listview`.

when I use `android:src ="@drawable/view1"` getting all the items and able to use scroll.

But whenever I use **background** in place of **src**

`android:background="@drawable/view1"` in image button, scroll does not work,why ?

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff">

 <include
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/header"/>

<ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="20dp"/>


<ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/ButtonViewCart"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/view1"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have to declare <scrollview> as root node

Comment: what do you mean by `make ListView Scrollable`? FYI Listview itself scrollable

Comment: Add `android:scrollbars="vertical"` to your `ListView`

Comment: @BobbeHoddi, thanks to edit, do you have any idea how can i solve this problem, yet no one has given correct answer

Answer (score 5):

ListViews are scrollable by default. If the number of items in your ListViews exceeds the amount that can be displayed on screen, then scrolling happens automatically.

Comment: I know scrolling happens automatically because listview is scrollable, but first read my question, what i have written?

Comment: I, for my part, don't know how you mean it. Do you mind to try to explain it a bit further?

Answer (score -1):

Create `<ScrollView>` as root node and try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbk" >

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff">

 <include
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/header"/>

<ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="20dp"/>


<ImageButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/ButtonViewCart"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/view1"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Two scrollable component together(Difficult for `Android` what to scroll) will going to create problem.

Comment: Have you ever tried your own `ListView` and `ScrollView` together?

Comment: @hotveryspicy you tell me what i need to use to get the list of items